# Adding a custom message to a @ExceptionHandler in Spring

Tags: java, spring, exception, annotations

I was wondering how it is possible to return a custom status code and message from a rest endpoint when throwing an exception. The code below allows me to throw my own, custom status code  571 when UserDuplicatedException is thrown, but I cant seem to fnd a way to give it an additional message or reason for the error. Can you help please?

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionResolver {

@ExceptionHandler(UserDuplicatedException.class)
public void resolveAndWriteException(Exception exception, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    int status = 571;
    response.setStatus(status);
}
```

}

Comment: `HttpServletResponse` has a `sendError` method, but that has other implications documented in its javadoc. Look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be straight forward.

Create custom error class:

```
public class Error {
    private String statusCode;
    private String message;
    private List<String> errors;
    private Date date;

    public Error(String status, String message) {
        this.statusCode = status;
        this.message = message;
    }

    //Getters - Setters 
}
```

And in your `@ControllerAdvice` as

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionResolver {

    @ExceptionHandler(UserDuplicatedException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Error> resolveAndWriteException(UserDuplicatedException e) throws IOException {
        Error error = new Error("571", e.getMessage());
        error.setErrors(//get your list or errors here...);
        return new ResponseEntity<Error>(error, HttpStatus.Select-Appropriate); 
    }
}
```